# Xcode 6 giving "LIBPNG ERROR TOO MANY IDAT'S FOUND" error

Tags: ios, xcode, png, libpng

Are there good tools for checking PNG files for issues that can be how I have ended up here? At first i feared with was an issue with the many thousands of "tiles" in my learning app (at 3 resolutions), but it seems one or more specific png files have an internal issue.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." That said, you may want to search for `pngcheck`.

Comment: I thought that describing the problem as "Xcode fails with 'too many idats' and a mention of libpng" and asking if for ways to check the png file was a reasonable question, if a bit leading by suggesting the solution might be in finding a problem with a png file. As indeed it was -- thanks for your "try pngcheck" - exactly what I was looking for..

Comment: http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/ is useful to  peek into the PNG structure. See for example if there are extra zero sized IDAT chunks.

Comment: @hangzhouharry  "exactly what I was looking for" Then you should upvote the answer and (perhaps) mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

[pngcheck](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/apps/pngcheck.html) works well and is a good resource. In addition, an OS-X app (in the app store) called "Quick Opaque" easily stripped out the (unneeded) alpha channel data from my png file, which cured the IDAT problem.