# Strange Xcode 9 issue , Can't add an app icon

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, xcode9.2

Whenever I add an app Icon to Asset Catalog and run on Device , it gives following error. This happens with every single project even, blank new projects.

> **Asset Catalog Compiler Error** /Users/****/Documents/Test/sfdadfas/sfdadfas/Assets.xcassets:
>   Failed to write image data for the app icon set from
>   "AppIcon.appiconset/app-icon-iphone@2x.png" to
>   "/Users/*****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sfdadfas-cbhytlfzznzesdsfsgifiloaxklokg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/sfdadfas.app/AppIcon60x60@2x.png".

But when I run on Simulator , this works fine and app icon is visible correctly.

I'm using Xcode 9.2 (9.1 had the same error) on macOS High Sierra.

Xcode 8.3.3 doesn't have this issue.

**EDIT**

Full Error on log,

> CompileAssetCatalog
>   /Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sfdadfas-cbhytlfzznzevlegifiloaxklokg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sfdadfas/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/sfdadfas.app
>   sfdadfas/Assets.xcassets
>       cd /Users/****/Documents/Test/sfdadfas
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool --output-format human-readable-text --notices --warnings --export-dependency-info /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sfdadfas-cbhytlfzznzevlegifiloaxklokg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sfdadfas/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/sfdadfas.build/Release-iphoneos/sfdadfas.build/assetcatalog_dependencies
>   --output-partial-info-plist /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sfdadfas-cbhytlfzznzevlegifiloaxklokg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sfdadfas/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/sfdadfas.build/Release-iphoneos/sfdadfas.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist
>   --app-icon AppIcon --compress-pngs --enable-on-demand-resources YES --sticker-pack-identifier-prefix com.*****.test22.sfdadfas.sticker-pack. --target-device iphone
>   --target-device ipad --minimum-deployment-target 10.3 --platform iphoneos --product-type com.apple.product-type.application --compile
>   /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sfdadfas-cbhytlfzznzevlegifiloaxklokg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sfdadfas/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/sfdadfas.app
>   /Users/****/Documents/Test/sfdadfas/sfdadfas/Assets.xcassets
>
> /* com.apple.actool.errors */
>   /Users/****/Documents/Test/sfdadfas/sfdadfas/Assets.xcassets: error:
>   Failed to write image data for the app icon set from
>   "AppIcon.appiconset/app-icon-iphone@2x.png" to
>   "/Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sfdadfas-cbhytlfzznzevlegifiloaxklokg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sfdadfas/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/sfdadfas.app/AppIcon60x60@2x.png".
>       Underlying Errors:
>           Description: pngcrush exited with signal '6' for "/Users/****/Documents/Test/sfdadfas/sfdadfas/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/app-icon-iphone@2x.png".
>   Error output:
>
> ```
> In /Users/****/Documents/Test/sfdadfas/sfdadfas/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/app-icon-iphone@2x.png,
> ```
>
> correcting libpng error: Too many IDAT's found
>
> /* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
>   /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sfdadfas-cbhytlfzznzevlegifiloaxklokg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sfdadfas/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/sfdadfas.app/Assets.car
>   /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sfdadfas-cbhytlfzznzevlegifiloaxklokg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sfdadfas/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/sfdadfas.build/Release-iphoneos/sfdadfas.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist

Comment: can you please share code sample with us

Comment: so we can check directely

Comment: Tried Deleting Derived data and Build Folder?

Comment: I'm trying this in a new project that doesn't have any code. Simply created a new project. and added an app icon in Xcode 9.2

Comment: @Mr.Bista yes i tried that too

Comment: @iMHitesh , I've edited the question with the full error.

Comment: check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060499/xcode-6-giving-libpng-error-too-many-idats-found-error